# get relative path with just file name and name of the parent folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a file path put together for writing to a CSV, I need to build the directory and have it display just a single column with parent folder and file name.

If I try it like this, I just get a display back of the file names and extension.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object @{l='WAV File';e={Split-Path -noQualifier ($_.Name) }}
```

WAV File
--------
test1.txt
test10.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
test5.txt
test6.txt
test7.txt
test8.txt
test9.txt

If I swap the `$_.Name` to `$_.FullName` I then get all the parent directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object @{l='WAV File';e={Split-Path -noQualifier ($_.FullName) }}
```

WAV File
--------
\tapes\12345\wav\test1.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test10.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test2.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test3.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test4.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test5.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test6.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test7.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test8.txt
\tapes\12345\wav\test9.txt

But the way I actually need it to display is `wav\test1.txt` so just a single parent directory. Can anyone advise where I am going wrong trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply [join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) the name of the file with the name of its directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{l='WAV File';e={Join-Path $_.Directory.Name $_.Name}}
```

Comment: You sir are a star, I have been looking at this for hours..... really appreciate it.